# How to remove the background image border when on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a card with an image header. When on hover of the card, I'd like to change the non-image part background color. Code as follows:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
      <img style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png);">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I use a background image as the image here because I need the `background-size: cover` effect, but as hovering on the card, you can see a border being added to the image due to it's actually a background image, I wonder how I can get rid of the border?

EDIT: the border isn't that obvious:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any border. what do you want do exactly ? remove background image & add color or what?

Comment: I'd like to keep the background image so I can have the `background-size: cover` effect, but without the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `background-image` attribute, you should use the style on a `<div>` tag instead (or any other tag you with `display:block`),  since this is an a background image not an image, I think this is caused by default browser behavior for not providing `src` attribute, which would be considered as `404` error for the image, not sure if this is the case here, here is a working snippet:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
}

.card-image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png);
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
      <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the `img` HTML element with a `background-image` CSS declaration. Two possible solutions:

1) Keep the `img` element, add a `src` attribute, and use the `object-fit` declaration.

HTML:

```html
<div class="card-image">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

2) Remove the `img` element (and declaration) and apply the `background-image` declaration to the `.card-image` element.

HTML:

```html
<div class="card-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.card-image {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```